# Excel: Using a formula (no VBA) how to check if elements in a range are in another array which is defined by index/match

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I'd have another question. The situation is as follows: I have two tables (=formatted Excel tables). The situation looks as below. I am trying to filter for the $ sales amount (cell E4) of a given sales rep (cell D4). I was thinking about using `=SUMPRODUCT(IF((Table2[Store ID]=INDEX(Table1[Store ID],MATCH("Marc",Table1[Sales Rep],0),)),1,0))` (as I would have other conditions such as month which are no displayed in my example below), however, that's not giving me the correct value. The index-formula gives me just the first result once it finds "Marc".

The "correct" result in the example shown would be $121 as Marc accounts for these sales in the store with ID 1.

How can I overcome this problem? Any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add an additional column [shop ok] with a formula `=IF(F7=$D$4,[@[store ID]],0)` into Table1, to indicate that this store is under Marc's control.

In E4 insert a formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT(Table2[Sales]* COUNTIF(Table1[shop ok],Table2[Store ID]))
```

It's an array formula, so add it using Ctrl+Shift+Enter

[image: example pic]

didn't manage to avoid adding additional columns, got some errors, so ended up with this solution for now.

Answer (score 0):

In `E4`, enter formula :

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(I7:I9,H7:H9,D7:D9)*(F7:F9=D4))
```

[image]